# Angular, cannot instantiate module: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception

I'm keep getting this exception in my console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=mainApp&p1=Error%3A…at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcinema%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A222)

........ angular.min.js:6
```

And the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
<title>This cinema...</title>
<!-- ... other tags -->
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

});
</script>
<!-- REST of the HTML body, but no angular used below -->
```

If I remove the `mainApp.config(func....` then it's working. I don't know how to set up routes. An empty function with a route provider generates the exception?

Comment: You haven't included the `angular-routing.js` script reference nor have you injected `ngRoute` into your `mainApp` module.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider):

> $routeProvider requires the `ngRoute` module to be installed.

So, you have to include the following script to your html:

```
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

and add the dependency to your module definition:

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: I have included the angular-route js file, now it's working. The problem still persist if I move my custom javascript code into another js file and include it in the html file:

<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

And the "js/main.js" file contains the code in my original post.

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian, don't forget to have a dependency on 'ngRoute' specified on your module definition. Here the working demo [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/EGqQDEN1EH8RdDxTZ8sw?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

`$routeProvider` requires a separate angular module `ngRoute`.  Download angular-route.js, add it to the page, and inject it into the angular.module method

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
<title>This cinema...</title>
<!-- ... other tags -->
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script>
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

});
</script>
<!-- REST of the HTML body, but no angular used below -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to using the `$routeProvider` without a `ngRoute` module.

See the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
<title>This cinema...</title>
<!-- ... other tags -->
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script>
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

});
</script>
<!-- REST of the HTML body, but no angular used below -->
```